# Restrict direct folder access via .htaccess except via specific links

Tags: apache, .htaccess, restrict

I want to restrict access to a folder on my server so that visitors may only access the contents (a web application) via links in the same domain.  Can I do this using .htaccess? To be clear, I simply want to prevent direct access to the contents so that visitors are routed through other pages on my website in order to get there.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me you want URL rewriting. Rewrite all URLs to point to a single point of entry (i.e. the index page), and have the route set as a GET variable (i.e. `index.php?r=css/file.css`).

This way, you have complete control over what goes where, and you can `include` or redirect your users accordingly.